# .htaccess simple exclude rewrite for a file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The problem is simple **in .htaccess** I want a specific file name that may have a .js or .css extension to be ignored from the following rewrite.

I have searched and tried several solutions - none of which seem to work. Most were just confusing gibberish to me as they seemed to not answer the question exactly. I feel like I am banging my head against a brick wall.

This is what I have using a rule, that doesn't work (it still rewrites the notme.css file)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/notme\.(js|css)$ $0 [L]     # doesn't work
# have also tried RewriteRule ^/notme\.(js|css)$ - [L]     # ditto

# any other file (js|css) should get processed by this rule
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.css$ /inc/css/css.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]      # main rule
```

I have also tried excluding with a RewriteCond prior to the rule but this also doesn't work

```
#same first 3 lines as above
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/notme\.(js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.css$ /inc/css/css.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]      # main rule
```

The action of the "main rule" is irrelevant (I have put all sorts of redirects there and they all redirect as expected but they all **ALSO act on the files they should NOT act on**

---

Another attempt:
cut the .htaccess down to absolute basics

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# the file /inc/css/notme.css should perform as normal css file it exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^notme\.css$ [NC]
# all other css files get 404ed (dump.php does not exist!)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.css$ /inc/css/dump.php?f=$1.css [L,QSA]
```

Still **NOT WORKING!**

**EVERY** css file gets 404ed 
the Cond is **not** doing what it should do: ie letting notme.css bypass the rule

[Test here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=dbe2f9c9-9a47-5d6b-b223-0fa1ae8767c0)

---

and NO there is no other .htaccess in the tree and this one is at root /

I have even just tried a new virtual server with only the file notme.css and this .htaccess and still url localhost/inc/css/notme.css goes to "dump.php not found"

Cannot believe there is no solution to this and the RewriteCond must be wrong.

Comment: Are you using these rules in a server config   or in an htaccess file?

Comment: @starkeen As said at the first line **in .htaccess** I do not have access to .conf on live server (tho am testing on localhost)

Comment: PS All - just ignore the .js for now as only testing for css as in "main rule" that rule will be changed to sort the .js later as $2

Comment: Then, you have to remove the leading slash from your rule's pattern , **^notme\.** should work.

Comment: @starkeed That sounded too simple (I thought it was one of many I had tried) But it didn't work url = localhost/inc/css/notme.css?123 still gets redirected to localhost/inc/css/css?f=inc/css/notme.css&123 and it should not